# Как расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "Бежать от них надо(,) и(,) чем дальше(,) тем быстрее". Где тут нужны запятые,а где нет?

Answer (score 1):

Но эта усилительная частица относится к "чем дальше", именно поэтому после неё запятую ставить нельзя. А вот перед И запятая нужна для для обособления обстоятельства. Так, по-моему.

Answer (score 0):

"Бежать от них надо, и чем дальше, тем быстрее."

По-моему, так.
Или как вариант:

"Бежать от них надо, и чем дальше -- тем быстрее."

Здесь от интонации зависит.

Comment: все-таки "и чем дальше" скорее присоединительная конструкция.
Далее цитата с этой страницы: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-037.htm

При союзном присоединении обычно употребляется запятая: Перед вами люди, имеющие в городе власть, и не малую (Н. И.). Иногда ставится тире: Дело мы делаем великое и сделали уже немало, а недостатки есть - и серьезные (Чак.).

Answer (score 0):

по-моему, перед ***и*** запятая не нужна, так как здесь ***и*** выступает не в роли союза, а в роли усилительной частицы

Comment: Да, но эта усилительная частица относится к "чем дальше", поэтому запятая нужна именно перед И, а не после.